# Caffe NetParameter parsing error

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I tried to load model and i got this error:

Check failed: ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: /home/Energetiks/builds/convolutional-pose-machines-release/testing/python/../../model/_trained_MPI/pose_iter_985000_addLEEDS.caffemodel
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
Aborted (core dumped)

pose_iter_985000_addLEEDS.caffemodel exists and the path is right.

Comment: Possibly it is corrupted. How did you generate this file?

Comment: I download it from the internet. This file worked on other computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved. I download file one more time and it works! Maybe I downloaded the wrong file the first time.